# download pdf files stored in database in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload

I store few pdf files in my db as binary format using the below code in my controller,

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        Image newImage = new Image();
        newImage.MimeType = file.ContentType;          

        var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
        newImage.Data = binaryReader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
        binaryReader.Close();
        objImage.InsertImage(newImage.Data);

        return View();

    }
```

now i want to download them back based on the id passed to the contrller that pdf files should be downloaded??

this is my code for pdf download, wat do i need to add more

```
    public ActionResult Download(int id)
    {
        DataSet da = new DataSet();

        da = objImage.getUserImage(id);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = da.Tables[0];
        Byte[] imagedata=(Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["UsImage"];



    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> this is my code for pdf download, wat do i need to add more

Return an ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult Download(int id)
{
    ...
    byte[] imagedata = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["UsImage"];
    return File(imagedata, "image/png");
}
```

and if you want the browser to popup a Save As dialog instead of displaying the image inline specify a filename:

```
public ActionResult Download(int id)
{
    ...
    byte[] imagedata = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["UsImage"];
    return File(imagedata, "image/png", "foo.png");
}
```

Obviously the MIME type and the filename could come from your database as well. In this example I have hardcoded them but you could adapt this code.

Comment: As I said you will have to adapt the MIME type to match the one in your database. If you have a PDF file adjust the code accordingly: `return File(imagedata, "application/pdf", "foo.pdf");`. The MIME type is something you should store in your database along with the file.

Comment: i used this, return File(imagedata, "application/pdf", "foo.pdf");..now it worked fine..unfortunately this is just test application which i need to implement in real time once it works perfectly, so for now i have only 2 columns id and the pdfdata column....

Answer (score 0):

return File(result.Content, result.Extension.Replace(".", ""));

```
public ActionResult Download(int id)
{
    DataSet da = new DataSet();

    da = objImage.getUserImage(id);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = da.Tables[0];
    Byte[] imagedata=(Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["UsImage"];


    return File(imagedata, "image/png");
}
```

Comment: this will just return images and if its pdf , then it will not return anything

Answer (score 0):

```
    public ActionResult GetPdf(int id)
    {

        ProjectProfile projectprofile = db.ProjectProfiles.Find(id);
        var image = projectprofile.pdf;
        return File(image, "application/pdf");
    }
```